# Java Edition in Android

Tags: android

I am a beginner of Android. Android is developed on java. Can anyone explain how android programs are compiled and run. Does every android phone contains jre installed if so which java Edition will android use J2SE or J2ME and which version java 7 or java 6 or java 8.

Edit: from data I gathered from other questions on stakeexchange and other websites they say android support java 7 from api 19. On some sites I read Google uses different flavour of java provided by apache. My main question is whether android phones contain jre or not. It's not whether android sdk will run on java in pc.

Comment: There is a plenty info over the Internet about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is the main language for Android development, but Android doesn't use the same jvm that a desktop uses. Android used Dalvik (DVM) and has been replaced by Android Runtime (ART) in Android Lollipop. There are requirements for having Java components for Android development, but you will likely get information on what you need to install from the following integrated development environments (IDEs) Android Studios (recommended and officially supported) or from Eclipse (previously officially supported). You will also need the Android SDK (software development kit) (Java) or the Android NDK (native development kit) (C, C++) or you might need both depending on the project. I hope this helps.

Comment: DVM replaced by ART does that change the way the program executes. Can you edit your with added info on difference between sdk and ndk.

Comment: Heres an article that while a few years old explains the transition from the DVM to ART. https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/art-vs-dalvik-introducing-the-new-android-runtime-in-kit-kat Heres a good write up on the use of the NDK https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html The NDK was more meant to be used sparingly while the SDK is the preferred development kit. I have before heard of developers thought that write an app in C++ and are able to build it in Android, iOS and Windows Phone.